# How to sort integer data from array list with multiple data type?

Tags: java, android, sorting

Hi everyone I need to know about sorting, suppose I have a custom array list with multiple data type, String and int and I want to sort the data according to price(int ) , for low to high or high to low, does anyone know how can I approach that? (Please notice that I am not asking about simple array list, I am asking about custom array list)

Thanks, here is my code:

```
  public static List<Data> data;
        String[] names= {"a","b","c","d",
                "e","f","g","h","i",
                "j","k","l","m","n",
                "o","p", "q","r","s",
                "t", "u","v","w","x","y","z"};

        Integer[] prices = {900000,450000,2100000,3200000,
                900000,2800000,1400000,800000,
                540000, 700000,650000,1000000,1300000,
                800000, 500000,1200000,900000,1500000,
                558000, 658000,400000,570000,900000,800000,400000};
        }

        private void loadData() {
            for (int i =0;i< 25;i++){
                data.add(new Data(names[i],prices[i]));
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Logic i made:

```
Collections.sort(data, new Comparator<Data>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Data o1, Data o2) {
                int returnVal = 0;
                if (o1.getPrice() < o2.getPrice()) {
                    String d = String.valueOf(o1.getPrice() < o2.getPrice());
                    returnVal = -1;
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "data" + String.valueOf(d), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (o1.getPrice() > o2.getPrice()) {
                    returnVal = 1;
                } else if (o1.getPrice() == o2.getPrice()) {
                    returnVal = 0;
                }
                return returnVal;
            } });
```

Comment: you want to sort your data List ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2784576/7320259 check this

Comment: Multiple data type means that is `List<Object>` and you puts there as well `Integer`s and `String`s or is it a `List<YourClass>` and `YourClass` contains fields of multiple types like `String` and `Integer`?

Comment: yes its a List<Object>

Comment: Let's close this as a duplicate and if by *custom List* you mean something exotic, feel free to reopen (or use a *regular List*)

Comment: Also note that you probably should use some `Map` here

Comment: @YCF_L  yes i want

Comment: i am using that

Comment: instead of making List<Obeject>, why don't you make your custom class with integer type price and String type name and after that make getters and setters? I think that would me much simpler. After that you can easily sort them.

Comment: i am using getter setter miss megha

Comment: Excuse me if it’s me not seeing it, @AnoopMishra: the logic added in your edit, is that more depth to the question or is it the answer to the question?

Comment: @OleV.V.   Length of arrays is:-
names---26
prices---25

Comment: Thanks, @ashishdhiman2007, for counting them for me. I have deleted my misleading comment.

Answer (score 0):

If your names[] will not have duplicate values, you should use a `TreeMap` to store such type of data. It will store the data in a sorted manner

This will declare your data.

```
Map<String,Integer> treemap=new TreeMap<String,Integer>();
```

Add elements to your map

```
treemap.put("a", 900000);
treemap.put("b", 450000);
```

Print sorted data:

```
for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : treemap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + " Value : " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Data {

private String names;
private Integer prices;

public Data(String names, Integer prices) {
    this.names = names;
    this.prices = prices;
}

public String getNames() {
    return names;
}

public void setNames(String names) {
    this.names = names;
}

public Integer getPrices() {
    return prices;
}

public void setPrices(Integer prices) {
    this.prices = prices;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Data{" +
            "names='" + names + '\'' +
            ", prices=" + prices +
            '}';
  }
}
```

---

```
class CustomComparator implements Comparator<Data> {

@Override
public int compare(Data o1, Data o2) {
    return o1.getPrices().compareTo(o2.getPrices());
  }
}
```

---

```
public static List<Data> data;

String[] names= {"a","b","c","d",
        "e","f","g","h","i",
        "j","k","l","m","n",
        "o","p", "q","r","s",
        "t", "u","v","w","x","y","z"};

Integer[] prices = {900000,450000,2100000,3200000,
        900000,2800000,1400000,800000,
        540000, 700000,650000,1000000,1300000,
        800000, 500000,1200000,900000,1500000,
        558000, 658000,400000,570000,900000,800000,400000,70000};

data=new ArrayList<>();

loadData();

Collections.sort(data, new CustomComparator());
```

Will give the output in Ascending prices, **In case there is a clash of prices** it will output chronologically (for those prices only)

Comment: cant taking compareto bro